# finding largest sum of contigious subarray through brute force python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find the largest sum of contiguous subarray through brute force. I wrote this algorithm, but it returns none. Where am I wrong?

```
a = [-13, -3, -25, -20, -3, -16, -23, -12, -5, -22, -15, -4, -7]




def max_Summ(a):
    max_sum = 0
    k=0
    for i in a:
        temp_sum = 0
        for j in a[k::]:
            temp_sum=temp_sum+j
            if temp_sum>max_sum:
                max_sum=temp_sum
        k=k+1
    return max_sum
print(max_Summ(a))
```

Comment: you dont have a `return` in your function

Comment: i added the return but it still returns 0

Comment: it means that `max_sum=temp_sum` never occurred OR `temp_sum` is zero. Right?

Comment: alright got it. This algorithm works for nonnegative sums only. If the sum<0, it will never reach the if statement. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 0):

It returns `None` because there is no return in the function.

```
a = [-13, -3, -25, -20, -3, -16, -23, -12, -5, -22, -15, -4, -7]




def max_Summ(a):
    max_sum = 0
    k=0
    for i in a:
        temp_sum = 0
        for j in a[k::]:
            temp_sum=temp_sum+j
            if temp_sum>max_sum:
                max_sum=temp_sum
        k=k+1
    return max_sum

print(max_Summ(a))
```

Comment: My bad. I am new and learning. But after adding return, it still returns 0

Comment: 0 is the correct result, isn't it? The empty array is a subarray of any array, and its sum is 0.